# Is SQL Server my bottleneck?

Tags: 2013, document-library, sql-server, library, performance

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm that serves as a document repository. We are seeing slowness searching for documents and paging through them as the document libraries grow. Is there any logging within SharePoint to show bottlenecks? I would love to see, for example, that 75% of the processing time is spent waiting for the SQL Server. I am familiar with performance metrics in SQL such as page life expectancy, buffer cache hit ratio, wait stats, etc. but it would be nice to see which server in the farm to focus my efforts on.

Comment: let us know your server farm topology? how many servers, server os, memory, cores, sql verion, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Developer dashboard](https://www.petri.com/sharepoint-2013-developer-dashboard-introduction) would definitely give you good inputs about what takes time when displaying a page.
Enable it from PowerShell:

```
$svc = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$dds = $svc.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$dds.DisplayLevel = "On"
$dds.Update()
```

And then make it appear from the UI (new icon appears in the top-right corner, under the settings wheel) to get a table with all timing information (including SQL requests durations).